# shell script using ncftpls in linux

Tags: shell, unix

I am using a shell script to fetch the latest files from a windows server. I am doing this using the following command:

```
ncftpls -m -u MYUSERNAME -p MYPASS ftp://abc.com/FOLDER \
  | sort +1 -2 --field-separator=\; \
  | tail -n1 | cut -d';' -f4 | sed 's/ //g'
```

Now I am trying to run the same script to fetch files from a Linux server. For that I modified the script like this:

```
ncftpls -m -u MYUSERNAME -p MYPASS ftp://abc.com/FOLDER \
  | sort +1 -1 --field-separator=\; \
  | tail -n1 | cut -d';' -f8 | sed 's/ //g'
```

But it is failing.
On the UNIX server it is listing two folders `.` and `..`.
I think those folders are causing the issue, so I want to list only the files in that folder without the `.` and `..` folders.

Any help please.

Comment: Show us the output of `ncftpls -m -u MYUSERNAME -p MYPASS ftp://abc.com/FOLDER \ `. The first impression is that by `| egrep -v "\.|\.\."` you can let keep them outside.

Comment: Thanks for the help I fixed it by using grep command. I want to list only csv/xml files. SO I used grep -i '\.csv\|\.xml$'